# Agrupar valores de um array em PHP

Tags: php, array, array-multidimensional

Tenho um formulário em forma de grid que me retorna os seguintes valores dentro de um Array:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=5)
      'pei_seq' => int 0
      'prg_cod_barra' => string '7899619704729' (length=13)
      'pei_prg_cod' => string '483' (length=3)
      'pei_valor' => string '42.00' (length=5)
      'pei_quantidade' => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=5)
      'pei_seq' => int 1
      'prg_cod_barra' => string '7899619704729' (length=13)
      'pei_prg_cod' => string '483' (length=3)
      'pei_valor' => string '42.00' (length=5)
      'pei_quantidade' => string '1' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=5)
      'pei_seq' => int 2
      'prg_cod_barra' => string '7899619704705' (length=13)
      'pei_prg_cod' => string '481' (length=3)
      'pei_valor' => string '31.00' (length=5)
      'pei_quantidade' => string '1' (length=1)
```

O que eu gostaria de saber é se há alguma função para unir os valores de `pei_quantidade` sempre que os valores de `prg_cod_barra` forem iguais.
No caso, queria que o array retornasse:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=5)
      'pei_seq' => int 0
      'prg_cod_barra' => string '7899619704729' (length=13)
      'pei_prg_cod' => string '483' (length=3)
      'pei_valor' => string '42.00' (length=5)
      'pei_quantidade' => string '2' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=5)
      'pei_seq' => int 2
      'prg_cod_barra' => string '7899619704705' (length=13)
      'pei_prg_cod' => string '481' (length=3)
      'pei_valor' => string '31.00' (length=5)
      'pei_quantidade' => string '1' (length=1)
```

Existe tal função?

Comment: Se os dados estão vindo repetidos é mais fácil vc dar um `GROUP BY` na hora da query mysql

Comment: Mas esses dados não vem do MySQL, são informados no formulário

Comment: não poderia usar o prg_cod_barra como chave principal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sugiro iterares essa array e fazer uma array nova durante a iteração. Em cada iteração precisas de verificar se já existe um valor igual na nova array.

Sugestão:

```
$nova = [];
foreach ($original as $arr) { // itera a array original
    $prg_cod_barra = $arr['prg_cod_barra'];
    $existe = false;

    foreach ($nova as &$subArr) { // iterar a array nova à procura de igual
       // se houver igualdade 
       if ($prg_cod_barra == $subArr['prg_cod_barra']){
          $valorAntigo = intval($subArr['pei_quantidade'], 10);
          $novoValor = intval($arr['pei_quantidade'], 10);
          $existe = strval($valorAntigo + $novoValor); // inserir o novo numero
          $subArr['pei_quantidade'] = $existe;
       }
    }
    if (!$existe) $nova[] = $arr;
}
```

#### Exemplo: https://ideone.com/drcgH5

Assumo que queres manter *string* no campo `pei_quantidade` daí que usei o `intval` para saber o valor da string e depois `stringval` para reconverter em string a soma dos valores.

Comment: Utilizei seu código e recebi uma array vazia como resultado, sabes o que pode ser?

Comment: @LucasPadilha tinha um erro, corrigí, deve ser `$nova[] = $arr;` no `else`. Não testei com código mas acho que agora a lógica está certa.

Comment: Eu já havia realizado esse teste haha. Ainda retornando uma array vazia.

Comment: Pelo que eu pude perceber, o código não está entrando na rotina do `foreach ($nova as $subArr)`

Comment: @LucasPadilha deste o nome de `$original` à tua array inicial?

Comment: sim, está adaptado ao meu código, mas não está entrando na rotina do segundo foreach. Acho que o erro está acontecendo pois a variável `$nova` não recebe valor nenhum, esta está retornando `array (size=0)
  empty`.

Comment: @LucasPadilha afinal tinha mais um erro no meu código. Agora tive tempo de consertar e juntei exemplo.

Comment: Já resolvi a questão de outro jeito, mas o seu funciona perfeitamente também. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Realizei alguns testes e consegui resolver meu problema. Aqui está o código que utilizei:

```
$nova = [];
foreach($origial as $a) {
  if (!isset($nova[$a['prg_cod_barra']])) {
    $nova[$a['prg_cod_barra']] = $a;
  } else {
    if ($nova[$a['prg_cod_barra']]['prg_cod_barra'] == $a['prg_cod_barra']) {
      $nova[$a['prg_cod_barra']]['pei_quantidade'] = strval($a['pei_quantidade'] + $nova[$a['prg_cod_barra']]['pei_quantidade']); 
    } 
  }
}
```

Ao realizar um `var_dump()` na variável `$nova` o retorno será:

```
array (size=2)
  '7899619704712' => 
    array (size=5)
      'pei_seq' => int 0
      'prg_cod_barra' => string '7899619704712' (length=13)
      'pei_prg_cod' => string '482' (length=3)
      'pei_valor' => string '0.04' (length=4)
      'pei_quantidade' => string '2' (length=1)
  '7899619704668' => 
    array (size=5)
      'pei_seq' => int 2
      'prg_cod_barra' => string '7899619704668' (length=13)
      'pei_prg_cod' => string '477' (length=3)
      'pei_valor' => string '51.00' (length=5)
      'pei_quantidade' => string '1' (length=1)
```

Comment: O que falta resolver?

Comment: Precisaria somente colocar a variável `pei_seq` em sequencia, mas isso foge do tópico da questão e não é tão importante quanto o que já foi resolvido.

Comment: @LucasPadilha veja se isso ajuda http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-multisort.php ou alguma dessas  http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/array.sorting.php

Comment: Resolvi, só coloquei um contador dentro do laço do `foreach` e atribuí o valor desse contador ao campo `pei_seq`. Mas obrigado da mesma forma.

Answer (score 0):

Achei um código que talvez possa te ajudar

```
$result = array();
foreach ($arr as $data) {
  $id = $data['prg_cod_barra'];
  if (isset($result[$id])) {
     $result[$id][] = $data;
  } else {
     $result[$id] = array($data);
  }
}
```

> Fonte [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12706456/2188149)

Comment: Não é exatamente o que eu procurava, mas já me deu uma luz, vou tentar adaptar isso ao projeto. Obrigado