# Agrupar os valores de um array PHP de acordo com a mesma chave.

Tags: php, array

Boa tarde pessoal,
Sei q a pergunta pode parecer repetitiva, mas já estou a um tempo procurando a solução para o meu caso, principalmente aqui no #stack.

Tenho o seguinte *Array()*:

```
array (size=9)
'Janeiro' => 
array (size=54)
  0 => 
    array
      'nome' => string 'Pessoa1' 
      'valor' => string '9' 
  1 => 
    array
      'nome' => string 'Pessoa2' 
      'valor' => string '2' 
  2 => 
    array
      'nome' => string 'Pessoa1' 
      'valor' => null 
  3 => 
    array
     'nome' => string 'Pessoa2' 
      'valor' => null
  4 => 
    array
      'nome' => string 'Pessoa3' 
      'valor' => null 
'Fevereiro' => 
 array
  0 => 
    array
      'nome' => string 'Pessoa1' (
      'valor' => string '28' 
  1 => 
    array
      'nome' => string 'Pessoa2' 
      'valor' => string '17' (length=2)
  2 => 
    array
      'nome' => string 'Pessoa3' 
      'valor' => string '2' (length=1)
  3 => 
    array
      'nome' => string 'Pessoa1' 
      'valor' => null
  4 => 
    array
      'nome' => string 'Pessoa2' 
      'valor' => null
  5 => 
    array
      'nome' => string 'Pessoa3' 
      'valor' => null
  6 => 
    array
      'nome' => string 'Pessoa4' 
      'valor' => null
```

...
E assim por diante contendo todos os meses atualmente.
Estou tentando retornar um array que ficasse assim:

```
 array
'Pessoa1' => 
array
  meses => v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7,v8,v9 
   array
'Pessoa2' => 
array
  meses => v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7,v8,v9
```

E assim por diante pegando todas as "Pessoas", só que como mostrado no exe. tem mês que o valor da pessoa é null e tem mês que ele tem valor, então preciso manter os valores null, ex [null,null,2,3,4,5,6,null,null]

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/53302/

Comment: @NoobSaibot utilizei esse exemplo como base mas não consegui retornar como postei na pergunta.

Comment: Mas a mesma pessoa aparece mais que um vez em determinados meses. Como funciona nesse caso ? Se puder construir um exemplo completo é o ideal para ficar facil de responder

Comment: Não acho que seja possível de outra forma, senão, executar uma lógica de loops e percorrer o array para encontrar todas as pessoas.... e outro loop percorrendo novamente para atribuir em quais meses e seus valores aquela pessoa aparece no array.... Acho que tem que ser na raça mesmo.... rsrsrs Relamente seria interessante um exemplo completo para testarmos e propormos a solução de um algoritmo mais interessante...
T+

Comment: @Isac Vou tentar explicar o contexto. Tenho o array de meses dentro desse array eu tenho o array pessoa que vai conter o nome dela e o valor e sim eu tenho dentro do array meses uma lista de todas as pessoas do meu BD que no caso ficariam com o valor null + as pessoas que tem algum dado cadastrado no campo valor, então eu tenho mes1[pessoa=> nome = pessoa1 valor = 10, nome = pessoa1 valor = null] ai nesse caso se ela tiver o campo valor diferente de null substitui, alguém tinha postado um cód quase com a solução mas ele deletou a resposta.

Comment: Bom se caso ainda n ficou claro posso criar um bin do array e postar aqui, pois é um pouco grande.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seguindo a estrutura do array apresentada você pode seguir uma iteração simples nos dados e construir o array futuro:

```
<?php

$registroGeral = [
    'Janeiro' => [
        [
            'nome' => 'Pessoa1',
            'valor' => '9'
        ],
        [
            'nome' => 'Pessoa2',
            'valor' => '2' 
        ],
        [
            'nome' => 'Pessoa1',
            'valor' => null 
        ]
    ],
    'Fevereiro' => [
        [
            'nome' => 'Pessoa1',
            'valor' => '28',
        ],
        [
            'nome' => 'Pessoa2',
            'valor' => '17',
        ],
        [
            'nome' => 'Pessoa3',
            'valor' => '2',
        ],
        [
            'nome' => 'Pessoa1',
            'valor' => null,
        ],
        [
            'nome' => 'Pessoa2',
            'valor' => null,
        ],
        [
            'nome' => 'Pessoa3',
            'valor' => null,
        ],
        [
            'nome' => 'Pessoa4',
            'valor' => null,
        ]
    ]
];

$frequenciaParticipante = [];
foreach ($registroGeral as $mes => $registros) {
    foreach ($registros as $registro) {
        if (!array_key_exists($registro['nome'], $frequenciaParticipante)) {
            $frequenciaParticipante[$registro['nome']] = [];
        }

        if (!in_array($mes, $frequenciaParticipante[$registro['nome']])) {
            $frequenciaParticipante[$registro['nome']][] = $mes;
        }
    }
}

var_dump($frequenciaParticipante); exit;
```

O resultado final ficará parecido com:

```
array(4) {
  'Pessoa1' =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    string(7) "Janeiro"
    [1] =>
    string(9) "Fevereiro"
  }
  'Pessoa2' =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    string(7) "Janeiro"
    [1] =>
    string(9) "Fevereiro"
  }
  'Pessoa3' =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    string(9) "Fevereiro"
  }
  'Pessoa4' =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    string(9) "Fevereiro"
  }
}
```

No final basta manipular os meses do participante como quiser

Comment: boa, seria isso mesmo, só preciso ajustar um pouco mais a saída se puder me ajudar agradeço, fiz essa edição no cod, `$frequenciaParticipante[$registro['nome']][] = $mes;   $frequenciaParticipante[$registro['nome']][] = $registro['valor'];`  e consegui o seguinte retorno `array 'Pessoa1' => array 0 => 'Janeiro' 1 =>  '9' 2 =>  'Fevereiro' 3 =>  '28' 4 =>  'Marco' 5 =>  '18'...`. Se eu retiro o $mes e deixo apenas o valor ele me retorna o valor e null junto e com $mes não, no caso agora estou tentando remover o $mes e deixar apenas os valores para que fique assim meses = [v1,v2,v3,v4]

Comment: Saída sem o $mes `'Pessoa1' => 
    array 
      0 => null
      1 => '2'
      2 => null
      3 => null
      4 => '3'
      5 => null
      6 => '2'
      7 => null
      8 => '5'
      9 => null
      10 => null
      11 => '2'
      12 => null
      13 => '11'
      14 => null`

Comment: Saída com o $mes `'Pessoa1' => 
    array
      0 => 'Janeiro' 
      1 => null
      2 => 'Fevereiro'
      3 => '2'
      4 => 'Marco'
      5 => null
      6 => 'Abril'
      7 => '3' 
      8 => 'Maio'
      9 => '2'
      10 => 'Junho'
      11 => '5'
      12 => 'Julho'
      13 => null
      14 => 'Agosto'
      15 => '2'
      16 => 'Setembro'
      17 => '11'`

Comment: Consegui, fiz o seguinte armazenei o valor de $mes em $meses e depois adicionei esse cod `$arr = [];
foreach ($frequenciaParticipante as $key => $value) {
    $resultado = array_diff($value, $meses);
    $arr[$key] = $resultado;
}` Muito obrigado pela ajuda, ja estava a dias atrás de uma solução para isso, vlw mesmo.

Comment: Que bom que conseguiu Diogo. Abraço!